# Save Dynamically generated PDF from Web browser control

Tags: vb.net, pdf, browser, controls

I have a web browser control in my windows form. I am trying to automate some process in a website. During this process, the invoice pdf has been generated dynamically and shown in the web browser control. I need to save that pdf locally. Please note: there is no direct link to download the pdf. I googled a lot past couple of days and haven't found any solution yet.

Can someone help me on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend handling the [`WebBrowser.Navigating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating.aspx) event. One of the parameters of this event is [`WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowsernavigatingeventargs.aspx) which has a property called [`Url`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowsernavigatingeventargs.url.aspx). If you're lucky, that property will end in `.pdf`. If you're not lucky you might have to perform a manual `HEAD` request and inspect the returned MIME-type to see if its a PDF.

Another thing that you could try is handling the [`WebBrowser.FileDownload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.filedownload.aspx) event but I'm not sure if it will be raised for PDFs viewed in-browser. If you have absolute control over the machine this is running on I would recommend disabling viewing of PDFs in the browser and just handle this event instead.